Pivot the Table in Oracle
I am trying to crack a Oracle query to pivot the date column to Years.
**Source:: **



ID
FY
CAL_DATE
Holiday Desc




P001
FY23
01/01/2023
New Years Day


P001
FY24
01/01/2024
New Years Day



Expected Output



ID
Holiday Desc
FY23
FY24




P001
New Years Day
01/01/2023
01/01/2024



Tried PIVOT which is not helping great . Please help me to create a dynamic SQL.
Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

We can use MIN and MAX with a GROUP BY clause.
For following sample data similar to yours, but extended by some other rows...
create table yourtable as
select 'P001' as id,'FY23' as fy, date '2023-01-01' as cal_date, 'New Years Day' as holiday 
union all
select 'P001','FY24',date '2024-01-01','New Years Day'
union all
select 'P002','FY22',date '2024-01-01','New Years Day'
union all
select 'P002','FY22',date '2023-01-01','New Years Day'
union all
select 'P002','FY22',date '2023-12-25','First Christmas Day'
union all
select 'P002','FY22',date '2024-12-25','First Christmas Day';

... following query...
SELECT
  id,
  holiday,
  MIN(cal_date) AS FY23,
  MAX(cal_date) AS FY24
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, holiday
ORDER BY id, holiday;

...will produce following result:



ID
HOLIDAY
FY23
FY24




P001
New Years Day
01-JAN-23
01-JAN-24


P002
First Christmas Day
25-DEC-23
25-DEC-24


P002
New Years Day
01-JAN-23
01-JAN-24



The only question I have would be if other than those two years can appear or if for one id both minimum and maximum date are in the same year. In those cases, the column names would be misleading. I think you will be able to change the column names if necessary, otherwise please clarify such cases in your question and tell us what to do then.

Try it like here:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( ID, FY, CAL_DATE, HOLIDAY_DESC) AS
        ( Select 'P001', 'FY23', DATE '2023-01-01', 'New Years Day' From Dual Union All
          Select 'P001', 'FY24', DATE '2024-01-01', 'New Years Day' From Dual
        )

--  S Q L :
Select   *
From     tbl 
PIVOT   ( Max(CAL_DATE) For FY IN('FY23' "FY23", 'FY24' "FY24" ) )              

/*    --  R e s u l t :
ID   HOLIDAY_DESC  FY23     FY24    
---- ------------- -------- --------
P001 New Years Day 01.01.23 01.01.24   */

